# merge de PDF cuando tienen nombres iguales

Tags: php

deseo poder hacer un merge de los archivos y para ello pienso que el primer paso sería clasificar los archivos por nombres iguales para hacer un merge, les comento lo que he realizado actualmente tengo un directorio con los siguientes archivos:

```
  _16_88888888.pdf
  _15_88888888.pdf
  _14_88888888.pdf
  _13_77777777.pdf
  _12_77777777.pdf
  _11_77777777.pdf
  _10_66666666.pdf
  _9_66666666.pdf
```

desearia unirlos de la siguiente forma:

```
   $filemerge.pdf
  _16_88888888.pdf
  _15_88888888.pdf
  _14_88888888.pdf

   $filemerge1.pdf
  _13_77777777.pdf
  _12_77777777.pdf
  _11_77777777.pdf
   
   $filemerge2.pdf
  _10_66666666.pdf
  _9_66666666.pdf
```

La libreria clegginabox/pdf-merger, me lo hace pero me pide que le pase los nombres de todos los archivos que quiero unir, obviamente debo pasarle por ejemplo, estos tres nombres

```
  _16_88888888.pdf
  _15_88888888.pdf
  _14_88888888.pdf
```

Como verán los debo pasar cuando tengan nombres iguales, en mi intento de hacerlo he realizado lo siguiente

Con siguiente código los agrupo por nombre en el indicie así:

```
            $archivos_iguales=[];

               foreach($ficheros1 as $archivo) {
                                   
                    $nom = substr($archivo,-12);
                                   
                     isset($archivos_iguales[$nom]) ? 
                     $archivos_iguales[$nom].= $archivo 
                     : $archivos_iguales[$nom]=$archivo;
                                   
                                   
               }
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
        "." => "."
        ".." => ".."
        "88888888.pdf" => "_16_88888888.pdf-_15_88888888.pdf-_14_88888888.pdf"
        "77777777.pdf" => "_13_77777777.pdf-_12_77777777.pdf-_11_77777777.pdf"
        "66666666.pdf" => "_10_88888888.pdf-_9_66666666.pdf"
```

pero necesitaría por ejemplo para hacer el merge decirle:

$pdfMerge->addPDF($archivos_iguales[$nom], 'all');

el sistema me dice que no consigue el archivo de nombre: _16_88888888.pdf-_15_88888888.pdf-_14_88888888.pdf obviamente el nombre del primer archivo es: _16_88888888.pdf, como haría para poder dividirlos por nombre? es decir para pasar los nombres pertenecientes a éste grupo unicamente:  "88888888.pdf" => "_16_88888888.pdf-_15_88888888.pdf-_14_88888888.pdf", y así sucesivamente con cada grupo?, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, gracias de antemano

Comment: a que te refieres con clasificar archivos cuando tienen nombres iguales; puedes dar una mejor explicación de que pretense que haga tu código??

Comment: la edite para ver si me comprenden mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás creando una cadena con los nombres de archivos y deberías hacerlo con un arreglo:

```
$archivos_iguales=[];
foreach($ficheros1 as $archivo) {
    if(strpos($archivo, '.pdf') === false) {
        // Omitir directorios y archivos que no son PDF
        continue;
    }
    $nom = substr($archivo,-12);
    // Verificar que existe el arreglo, o crearlo
    if(!isset($archivos_iguales[$nom])) {
        // No existe, crear arreglo vacío
        $archivos_iguales[$nom] = [];
    }
    // Agregar archivo al arreglo
    $archivos_iguales[$nom][] = $archivo;
}
```

Te va a generar un arreglo como este:

```
"88888888.pdf" => [
    "_16_88888888.pdf",
    "_15_88888888.pdf",
    "_14_88888888.pdf"
],
"77777777.pdf" => [
    "_13_77777777.pdf",
    "_12_77777777.pdf",
    "_11_77777777.pdf"
```

Solo necesitas recorrer en un ciclo:

```
foreach($archivos_unicos as $numero => $archivos) {
    // Creas el nuevo documento
    $pdfMerge = new \Clegginabox\PDFMerger\PDFMerger;
    // Recorres los archivos de este grupo
    foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
        // Agregas
        $pdfMerge->addPDF($archivo, 'all');
    }
    // Guardas con el número que corresponde
    $pdfMerge->merge('file', "ruta/{$numero}", 'P');
}
```

Comment: Miles de gracias estaba estancada muchas gracias